# Reduce carousel height with bgstretcher

Tags: css

I have to work on a webdesign (I'm not webdesigner at all...) and I would like to reduce the height of a carousel working with bgstretcher.

http://santiano-info.fr/joomla3/

I'd like to have a very small gap between the top menu and the compass, I've tried to deal with various heights, but I can't figure out how to do it...

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Please try to reduce: `.header-inner a { margin: 252px 0 0 0; }`.

Comment: Very simple... that's it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @emmanuel, the answer was : `.header-inner a { margin: 252px 0 0 0; }`